# ionic select with multiple=true

Tags: ionic-framework

i am loading a page in ionic with values fetching from php, Eg. edit profile page.
Here i am using an `<ion-select multiple="true">` item. Here when user selects multiple values then in php side i am ready the array object and storing the values of selected items as "Delhi,Koltata,Mumbai".

Now the challenge i am facing is how to show those values as selected when the ionic page is loaded. I am using like --

```
<ion-select multiple="true" value="{{vcity}}" placeholder="Select city" name="city" [(ngModel)]="postData.city">
```

But when the `<ion-select>` is loading it's showing blank, that i understood for sure as values of vcity here is "Delhi,Koltata,Mumbai" which is not readable to `<ion-select value="{{vcity}}">`

So how i can make this thing happen. Any idea for startup.

THank you

This is my current code, here the problem is that the values are not getting selected when the page loads --

```
<ion-select multiple="true" placeholder="Select Caste" name="caste" [(ngModel)]="postData.caste">
                            <ion-select-option *ngFor="let caste of casteData" value="{{caste.name}}" selected='caste.selected ? "selected" : "" '>{{caste.name}}</ion-select-option>
                        </ion-select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally i got my solution. I want to thank @Mostafa Harb, i am up-voting your answer for the help, for guiding and helping me, using your codes and with some on tweaking i finally got what i wanted. Here is what i have done .

```
        this.casteData = [];
        const splitValues = this.vcaste.split(',');
        for (const data of splitValues) {
          this.casteData.push(data);
        }



<ion-select multiple="true" [value]="casteData" placeholder="Select Caste" name="caste" [(ngModel)]="postData.caste">......</ion-select>
```

Here in "casteData" array the selected values are present which is supplied to the `ion-select` as `[value]="casteData"`

Answer (score 1):

Inside you ts file declare new varaible example  :

```
cities = [];
```

then inside ngOnInit() or the place your getting the vcity value from... use:

```
const splitValues = vcity.split(',');
for(let i =0;i<splitValues.length;i++) {
    cities.push({name : splitValues[i]});
}
```

**Also Edited** In ion-select just edit  ngmodel="splitedValues"
And Inside ion-select add :

```
   <ion-select-option *ngFor="let city of cities">{{city.name}}</ion-select-option>
```

**Edited Part :**
According to you edits in variable names:

1. First remove the selected="...." part since its wrong.
2. Second thing (this is up to you and you can skip it) , in the value
   of selected option , its always better to set an id since it should
   be unique value except if city name will not be decalred again so
   that will cause no problem...
3. Third thing which is important to make the selection which is
   passing the values you need to be selected in ngModel, it could be
   the splitValues we defined as const, you can change it to become
   this.splitValues and decalre SplitValues in ngModel or if you wanted
   to work with second number which i told it's up to you is to make
   anothet splitValues variable but for id's of cities and thus change
   the ion-select-option value in your code to [value]="caste.id" or value="{{caste.id}}"

Comment: Hi bro, thanks for the solution, its working great, but just 1 issue, How to make these ion-select-option selected or checked?

Comment: @Ritesh gupta ,what do you mean by that? The ion select option will put a radio button for single choice in android and checkbox for ios and for multiple choice by default will put checkbox for both platforms android and ios. But where is your problem exactly ? I didn't what you want..

Comment: Ok, so let me explain the situation, This page where i kept your mentioned solution is the Edit Profile page, so when this page loads, it is showing user the already selected cities along with the list of other cities, so as per your solution i am able to display the selected cities from the database in the <ion-select> along with the other city names in the same <ion-select>, but the issue i am facing is the selected city values are not getting ticked in the checkbox inside the <ion-select>

Comment: selected="selected" is for static use if you have predefined select and you want to select the items manually, while if you want it dynamic process , you could use [selected]="city.selected ? "selected" : "" ' , this means that inside the split values add beside name: splitvalues[i] ,  selected:and put from db if value is selected is true or false, and thus if true the tick will occur on item wlse will not mark it as selected.

Comment: bro, done it as per your suggestion but selected part is not working, i tried the same using static value also selected="selected", but its not getting selected.

Comment: Ok if you can wait me 40 mins and i'll be near my computer and will see you the exact since i'm using mobile and working on what i remember

Comment: FYR i have added my current code at the end of my question, thank you

Comment: @Riteshgupta i eddited thr answer and that the way i do, just inside the splited values that will be binded to ngmodel, it should contain only the names or id's (as descussed in answer) that are selected by the user in order to make them selected else if you put the whole splitted values all will be selected and any question i'm ready to answer and sorry for delay in answering but i got in problem and couldn't get my computer at time.. any way tell me about anything you need...